# displaying values in jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have created a bar chart using jquery flot and i have been asked to display the value of the bar above the bar. Something like i have mocked up **in red** in this image? The documentation isnt clear on how i can achieve this. Any ideas?

[image]

I have included the options i have used below.

```
        var options = {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    dataLabels: true
                }
            },
            bars: {
                align: "center",
                barWidth: 0.5,
                horizontal: true,
                fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 0.5 }, { opacity: 1}] },
                lineWidth: 1
            },

            yaxis: {
                mode: "categories"
            },
            xaxis: {

            },
        valueLabels: {
               show: true
              }
        }
$.plot("#placeholder", series, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you are using [this version](https://github.com/leonardoeloy/flot-valuelabels) of the value-labels plugin.

What you can do is set the `showAsHtml:true` option in the `valuesLabels` section, and then add this to your CSS:

```
.valueLabels {
        font-size:70%;
        color:black;
}
div.valueLabelLight {
        opacity:0.5;
        background-color: white;
        border:none;
        position:absolute;
}
div.valueLabel {
        position:absolute;
        border:none;
}
```

Then you can change those CSS values however you like to change how the labels look (i.e. set `color:red` instead of `color:black` for `.valuesLabels`).

Further, to add the `%` sign, you need to add this to your `valuesLabels`:

```
labelFormatter: function(v){
   return v+'%';
}
```

So you will end up with this in your flot options:

```
    valueLabels: {
        show: true,
        align: 'center',
        showAsHtml: true,
        labelFormatter: function (v) {
            return v + '%';
        }
    },
```

One of the key things seems to be that the options for `valuesLabels` go *inside* the `series` options, not at the top level.

See it somewhat working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/3z4yf/

Comment: this plugin (valuesLabels) doesn't work  with y-axis Categories & Horizontal bars. Some src code modifications required